# Access to the path is denied && Attempted to perform an unauthorised operation

Tags: vb.net, pipe

I tried to create a client side named pipe program connected to server piped program but it encountered to have this problem.

```
"Access to the path is denied"

clientpipe = New System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream
("192.168.1.1","soohhead",Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, Pipes.PipeOptions.None)

clientpipe.connect()
```

-When I tried to modify the code as below, It will return me another error message as
   "Attempted to perform an unathorized operation".

```
clientpipe = New  System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream
("192.168.1.1","soohhead",Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, Pipes.PipeOptions.None)

clientpipe.connect()

ps = New PipeSecurity()
ps = clientpipe.GetAccessControl()
ps.AddAccessRule(New PipeAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", 
PipeAccessRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow))

clientpipe.SetAccessControl(ps)
```

In return My client pipe still unable to connect to server pipe program, Appreciate thanks to anyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pulling your solution out of the question and placing it here for future assistance to other users.

Server Pipe:

```
ps = New System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity

ps.AddAccessRule(New System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule("Users", 
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

ps.AddAccessRule(New System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule("CREATOR OWNER", 
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

ps.AddAccessRule(New System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRule("SYSTEM", 
System.IO.Pipes.PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))

serverpipe = New System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("soohhead", 
Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, 10, Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode.Message, 
Pipes.PipeOptions.None, 4024, 4024, ps)
```

Client Pipe:

```
clientpipe = New System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream
("192.168.1.1","soohhead",Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, Pipes.PipeOptions.None)

clientpipe.connect()
```